# How to access an element's value in field validation function

Tags: entities

Drupal form api reference example for `#element_validate` accesses element's value with `$element['#value']` in field validation function:

```
function myelement_validate($element, &$form_state, $form) {
   if (empty($element['#value'])) {
     form_error($element, t('This field is required.'));
   }
}
```

But `$element['#value']` is always empty for me. indeed in `print_r($element)` there is no key named `#value` in first dimension of the array. instead, it is in somewhere like `$element['und'][0]['#entity']....`

My code:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if (isset($form['field_myfield'])) {
      $form['field_myfield']['#element_validate'][] = 'myfield_validate';

   }
}

function myfield_validate($element, &$form_state, $form) {

   //print $element['#value']; exit; // returns nothing

   if (!empty($element['#value']) && !is_numeric($element['#value'])) { // always false
      form_error($element, t('Error'));
   }
}
```

Is anything wrong?

Comment: You can get values from the $form_state argument of the validation function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a value using $form_state like as follow

```
$form_state['values']['field_myfield'];
```